# Why AnyObject to value type cast succeed?

Tags: swift

We know that `AnyObject` can only represent an instance of any class type. [Link](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html#ID342)

I have `SimpleStruct` structure:

```
struct SimpleStruct {
    var value: Int = 0
}
```

And `casting()` Function

```
func casting() { //1
    var ss1: AnyObject //2
   // ss1 = SimpleStruct(value: 10) //Value of type 'SimpleStruct' does not conform to 'AnyObject' in assignment
    ss1 = SimpleStruct(value: 10) as AnyObject //4
    if let ss = ss1 as? SimpleStruct { //Why is this casting succeed //5
        print(ss.value) //6  "print 10"
    }
}
```

In line 3 structure assignment in `AnyObject` var is not possible.

Why in line 4 `SimpleStruct` to `AnyObject` casting and assignment is successful?

Why in line 5 `AnyObject` to `SimpleStruct` casting and assignment is successful?